# Angular ng-show flickering in IE 10

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an issue with the angular `ng-show` directive.
I have 2 buttons which are working like a toggle button.

**index.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        ng-show="!isShow" 
        ng-click="showDeleted()">
        Show deleted items
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        ng-show="isShow" 
        ng-click="showDeleted()">
        Hide deleted items
</button>
```

**myController.js**

```
$scope.showDeleted = function(){
  $scope.isShow = !$scope.isShow;
};
```

When i click on the button everything is working fine, but in IE10 I can see the hided button flickering. Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6bLVt4pQm17o6MqVSY2h?p=preview) if you need one.

Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, you should name your showDeleted method toggleDeleted since it handles both showing and hiding

Comment: @cs.matyi Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @klashar It was an old Issue of my. Not yet. If I remember correctly, I use ng-if instead ng-show/ng-hide and use the ng-cloack n the whole html document.

Comment: @cs.matyi, I had the issue in Angular UI issue and it was fixed by using latest version of Angular UI - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.1.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ng-cloak
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display

I think all angular apps (that doesn't use ng-include to load template)
should use ng-cloak to prevent to hide all templates until angular compiles it.